# The same operation for many pairs in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

In Python, I would like to evaluate a function for an array, however, an array of pairs (or more generally arrays).

I know I can do this operation for an array of scalars:

```
def f_test(scalar, pair):      
    return scalar + pair[0] + pair[1]

result = f_test(numpy.linspace(0, 9, 10), [3, 4])
```

And get the desired result:

```
[  7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.  16.]
```

So the pair is fixed and the scalar is taken from an array.

The question is: Can it be done it the other way? With the scalar kept fixed... **Can the pairs be taken from a vector to obtain again a vector of the same length as the result?**

That is for (something like, e.g. not necessarily a numpy.array)

```
scalar = 0
pair = numpy.array([ [1,2], [3,7], [5,8] ])
```

obtain

```
[ 3, 10, 13 ]
```

instead of

```
[4, 9]
```

Note: I have simplified the operation I need to perform on the numbers a lot to keep the example simple.

If it can't be done or to be more general: **What is the best practice (in Python!) to perform the same operation on a large number of arrays?**

Note: I was searching this topic and even found some similar questions. However, I was not sure if they are really the same and more importantly did not found the answer. As it seems to me as a generally desirable operation, I asked a separate question.

Comment: Despite the name, your function isn't working with a `scalar`.  It is adding the 2 elements of `pair` to an array, i.e. adding two scalars to an array.  I suspect you need more practice with adding arrays of varying shapes.  The key is understanding how broadcasting works.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but if your computation is expressible as linear algebra, this is crying out to be formulated as a matrix multiplication problem, it will be so much faster. In particular you can use the old 3D graphics trick and add a dummy row of 1's to handle the term `scalar * 1`. So have your input be a 3 x m matrix, where the third row is ones. You need to tell us more about what your actual computation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) `pair`:

```
f_test(scalar, pair.T)
#array([ 3, 10, 13])
```

Or you could use list comprehension:

```
[f_test(scalar=scalar, pair=p) for p in pair]
#[3, 10, 13]
```

---

#### Timing results

Looks like the first method is way faster. For an array of length 100,000 the speed improvement is ~270X on my computer!

```
N = 100000
scalar = 0
pair = np.array([[np.random.randint(0,10), np.random.randint(0,10)] for i in range(N)])

# Using transpose
%%timeit
f_test(scalar, pair.T)
#1000 loops, best of 3: 229 µs per loop

# List comprehension
%%timeit
[f_test(scalar=scalar, pair=p) for p in pair]
#10 loops, best of 3: 62 ms per loop
```

Comment: How simple :) Thank you also for the timing comparison.